# Meta collection or database of structured vocabularies

Tags: linked-data, ontology, semantic-web

A short question; does a meta aggregation or collection of ontologies and structured vocabularies which exist out there, each single ones being ready to be used as linked data? (ideally with links to each other)?

I would expect such a collection to be made publicly available by an association or a consortium in the semantic web domain, but I'm not much into it (actually, I discovered this familys of concept a few days ago only, and things are fuzzy so I'm still learning about it).

I found [this](https://www.w3.org/standards/semanticweb) page until now but without any list of that sort.

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for ontologies:

- https://archivo.dbpedia.org/
- https://lov.linkeddata.es/

But there's maybe 5k ontologies, how do you hope to overview them and learn about them? You should start from a specific (narrow) problem domain.